# Linear Algebra - Subspaces in P3

Tags: linear-algebra

A bit confused on these two questions, are these subspaces of P3 (P3 denotes the space of polynomials of degree at most three)
$$S = \{a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 \in P_3 : a_1 = 0 \hspace{4pt}\text{or}\hspace{4pt} a_3 = 0\}$$
and
$$C = \{p\in P_3 : p = 0 \hspace{4pt}\text{or}\hspace{4pt} p(0) \neq p (1)\}$$

Thanks

Comment: please consider formatting your question with mathjax.  Also what is P3?

Comment: @Ellusionist - I would but I dont know how to use mathjax, and P3 denotes the space of polynomials of degree at most three.

Comment: Can i ask why this has been down-voted?

Comment: I down-voted the question as you did not use Mathjax. Additionally, your question did not contain all information - e.g. the definition of $P_3$.  Also you did not include what you have tried so far. For instance we don't know why you are confused. Is it because you don't know the definitions, or because you tried something and got stuck solving that problem?

Comment: Right, well I don't think you should just look at a question and think that deserves a down-vote because I simply don't know how to use a program, I've seen many new users on here ask questions without using mathjax and people have been kind of enough to ask there questions. It was easily understandable without the MathJax. I then edited the question and put in what was P3 maybe 2-3 mins after, i thought people would understand what P3 was due to the nature of the equation in S. 

I'm stuck because I have no clue how to start proving, i.e. the 3 properties required.
Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It takes 2 minutes to read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) mathjax tutorial.

Comment: Right, I shall have a read. But is there still a reason to down-vote the question? All of your problems have been answered. And next time instead of down-voting a question straight away, it takes around 10-20 seconds to write a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ was  subspace of $P_3$ the sum of elements in $S$ would also have to be in $S$, but this is clearly not the case, since for example $p(x)=x\in S$ and $q(x)=x^3\in S$, but $p(x)+q(x)=x+x^3\notin S$, thus $S$ is not a subspace of $P_3$.
$C$ is also not a subspace, since for example $p(x)=1+x\in C$ and $q(x)=1-x\in C$, but $p(x)+q(x)=2\notin C$.
Also what are the coefficients for polynomials in $P_3$?
probably not relevant here but it should be said.

Comment: I can see you're trying to disprove the property: p(x) + q(x) ∈ S, but how did you get p(x)=x and q(x)=x^3, and thank you for explaining C, I understand that fully now.

Edit: Are you just starting that x is in P3 and so is x^3?

Comment: you can just define $p$ and $q$ like that, and we know that $p,q\in S$, since in $p$ $a_3=0$ and in $q$ $a_1=0$.  What is the problem here? and $p+q\notin S$, since $a_1\neq 0$ and $a_3\neq 0$.

Comment: so you can just disregard a0 and a2, and show p and q as just x and x^3?

Comment: Also, "Also what are the coefficients for polynomials in P3?" - the coefficients can be anything unless defined.